# how can I map a network location in Windows 10 to an FTPS location?

Tags: networking, windows-10, webdav, ftps

[Add Network Location, Map FTP Drive in Windows 10/8/7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows) works with ftp:// prefix but fails with ftps:// prefix under Windows 10.

my hosting provider 1&1 offers FTPS but it seems I can not use FTPS with the simple method above in which no third party software like Filezilla is necessary.

while FTP works, FTPS is substantially more secure for updating my websites.

some articles suggest WebDAV as an alternative; I know very little about WebDAV; FWIW, my intuition says FTPS mapping is the *simplest* solution if I can get it to work.

Comment: in order to transfer files securely over FTPS you need encryption which obviously is not native to windows, but FTP is so thats why FTP works. In order to use FTPS you need to use Filezilla or similar.

Comment: WebDAV isn't necessarily secure, in fact, I am almost sure it isn't

Comment: If I recall correctly, for WebDAV to be secure, it has to go over https.